# Problems with input form

Tags: php, mysql

I created a simple form through with I would like to update some info in mysql database. I through it all looks fine but i get some error

I got (two files):

```
<?php

$db_name = "test2";
$un = "jharvard";
$pw = "crimson";
$host = "localhost";

$connect = mysql_connect($host, $un, $pw);
mysql_select_db($db_name) or die(mysql_error());

echo ("succesfully conneted to the database!");

?>
```

and

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submitted']))

{


//Dit is de php file waarmee je connectie met de database maakt.
include ("addEmployee.php");

    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];

    $sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO customers (name, address) VALUES ('$fname', '$lname')";

    if (!mysqli_query($connect, $sqlinsert))

    {
    die ('error!');
    }



}


?>


<html>
```

```
Add somebody!
```

```
<body>

    <form method= "post" action="oefInsertData.php">

        <input type = "hidden" name ="submitted" value="true" />

        First name: <input type = "text" name="fname"/>
        Last name: <input type = "text" name="lname"/>

        <input type="submit" value="Add new person"/>

    </form>




</body>
```

If i run it I get the following error: ! ) Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource given in /home/jharvard/vhosts/pset7/public/oefInsertData.php on line 16

Anybody know what goes wrong here?

Comment: you have switch from `mysql_` to `mysqli_`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using both `my_sql` and `my_sqli` extension together..

Use this..

```
$connect = mysqli_connect($host, $un, $pw, $db_name);
```

and avoid

```
mysql_select_db($db_name) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
<?php

$db_name = "test2";
$un = "jharvard";
$pw = "crimson";
$host = "localhost";

$connect = mysql_connect($host, $un, $pw);
mysql_select_db($db_name) or die(mysql_error());

echo ("succesfully conneted to the database!");

?>
```

with

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","jharvard","crimson","test2");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have switch from `mysql_` to `mysqli_` so `$connect` is not a mysqli parameter change this by using `mysqli_connect` [reference](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php

$db_name = "test2";
$un = "jharvard";
$pw = "crimson";
$host = "localhost";
?>
and
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submitted']))
{
//Dit is de php file waarmee je connectie met de database maakt.
include ("addEmployee.php");
mysql_connect("$host", "$un", "$pw")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];

$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO customers (name, address) VALUES ('{$fname}', '{$lname}')");
if(!$query){ echo mysql_error(); }

}


?>
```